# aiohttp.ClientSession() in Quart

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp, quart

How can I create an aiohttp.ClientSession() once so that I can use it when a request is received? And I'd like to deploy this later with Gunicorn as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [startup function](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/how_to_guides/startup_shutdown.html) via the before_serving decorator,

```py
@app.before_serving
async def startup():
    app.client = aiohttp.ClientSession()

@app.get("/")
async def index():
    await app.client.get(...)
```

As Quart is a ASGI framework you'll need to use an ASGI server such as Hypercorn rather than Gunicorn (a WSGI server).

Comment: Will it be created in the event loop and how will it close (as there isn't an explicit close) ? Just wondering based on https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/faq.html#why-is-creating-a-clientsession-outside-of-an-event-loop-dangerous

Comment: Yep, before_serving functions are guaranteed to run in the correct event loop. You can use a after_serving to close.

Comment: would you redeclare Quart to include `client` here ? `class Quart(Quart)` works but not sure if good practice.

Comment: I often do that to help with type checking.